# R exporting WebGL for use in Reveal.js

Tags: javascript, html, r, webgl, reveal.js

Hello I am using R for some bioinformatics but don't know any html/javascript and am trying to use a 3d plot in a reveal.js presentation. In r's RGL package there is a function called writeWebGL which "Writes the current scene to a collection of files that contain WebGL code to reproduce it in a browser". This does work but I want to put the scene in a reveal.js presentation. The problem is every time I try to put the code in the editor I get "Removed 'script' tag found in deck." and the slide only shows the "You must enable Javascript to view this page properly." backup the code has. Is it possible to have webGl in a reveal.js presentation and if so how would you do so?

Thank you very much for your time.